# SSRS FieldValue denying ReportItems

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-expression

While trying to preview the SSRS report I'm building, I'm getting the below error message:

> (processing):Unknown ExpressionType: FieldValue denying ReportItems.

I haven't been able to find anything pertaining to this error anywhere. My report is fairly simple, mostly just lookup expressions referencing connected SQL tables. The only thing that has been added is a string parameter with a set readonly value. I experimented with removing it from the expressions it is used in, but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I imagine one of your expressions is wrong from the error you are getting. Try removing them one by one

Comment: The [tag:processing] tag should only be used for questions about the Processing language.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error message and found that I had used a ReportItems!FieldName.Value reference in a Dataset calculated field.